# Sending a POST request in SOAP UI with plain text payload

Tags: soapui, postman

I have to test a POST request in SOAP UI which looks something like this in POSTMAN.

[image: Postman image]

While replicating the same in SOAP UI, I cant pass the body as body type "text" is not available in SOAP UI.

Is there any alternative to that?

This is what the SOAP request looks like

[image: SOAPUI]

Comment: What headers are you sending in that image? What does the request look like in SOAPUI?

Comment: I have added the soap image along with headers. The problem is not with the request but how to pass the string in the body using SOAP UI

Comment: Can you not just add the `Content-Type` `text/plain` header to the SOAP? This is the header that would have been automatically set in Postman if you selected the `raw` > `Text` option.

Comment: the content-type is limited to 1.application/json 2.application/xml 3.text/xml 4.multipart/form-data 5.multipart/mixed

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use Soap then, sounds like you’re going to get what you want from Postman.

Comment: Danny's point about just using Postman is a good one, but I'm curious why you can't do what you want in SoapUI.  The body of your SoapUI request ought to have some XML tag to indicate what that long value is.  It might even just say <body><myStringName>The String</myStringName></body> .  Or it may even just be <myStringName>The String</myStringName>, but I think it needs to be something.  In Postman, see what it actually sends to the server, than compare that against the raw request in SoapUI, you might be able to see what is missing then.

Comment: I want to create test suites to pass the web services externally(preferably from a csv or excel sheet) and subsequently add assertions ,which is why i want to use SOAPUI instead of postman. Except the part where i have to pass the string in the body there doesn't seem to be any other limitation in SOAPUI. I was hoping to get a work around for this.

Comment: Shivasish, in my comment above, I suggested looking at what Postman actually sends to the server (SoapUI equivalent is the raw request), you should be able to see what Postman has wrapped around your string to enable it to send to server.  If you can paste that value, then I might be able to help.

Comment: Do you know how to check what Postman actually sends to the server?

Comment: Yes, kind of.  In Postman where you have your working request, on the same tool bar as 'Auth Headers Body etc', there is a right-aligned button  labelled 'Code'.  Click that and you can obtain a the code for your request.  You can use the drop down to select the code fragment int he language of your choice.  Try the dropdown for a few of options and compare to the soap ui request you have created.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for an answer for this, or if you're just simply confused with the UI of SoapUi. On this [page](https://www.soapui.org/docs/rest-testing/working-with-rest-requests/) there is a statement:

> The Media Type box provides a number of standard media types for the request body, but you are free to enter any other value instead

You can type in `text/plain` for Media Type, and add the text you want to send in the text field.